# El significado de la palabra "picnic"

Tags: modismos

Tengo aquí la letra de la canción, [*Picnic en el 4b*](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=81707), que fue compuesta por el mismo grupo Soda Stereo. La letra de la rola va así:

> Picnic en el 4ºB 
>   Es una cuestión de voltaje 
>   Picnic en el 4ºB 
>   Ya me acostumbraste

Que significa la palabra "picnic" en este contexto? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no tiene un significado distinto en ese contexto. No es que la letra de la canción tenga sentido del todo (lo cual es normal en música y poesía) pero creo que el sentido es prácticamente literal: hacer un *picnic*  no en el campo o en el parque, si no en el salón de mi piso, el apartamento 4ºB. También puede ser que donde dice "picnic" quiera referirse a una fiesta (usando la palabra "picnic" como una suerte de eufemismo).

Especialmente viendo el verso siguiente, creo que se trata de un picnic (ya sea un "picnic" como tal o una alusión a una fiesta) en un apartamento.

> Golpean la puerta
>
> Por décima vez
>
> Es que falta alguien por venir
>
> Cuando me suba esa cara de gaste
>
> Y me baje el alcohol
>
> Entre el alud podré asomar mi nariz
>
> Y salir a la calle